# different controls in one column gridview, devexpress winform

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

How add different controls in one column GridView?
I want it to be like this.
Without creating separate gridviews, for other controls.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I see, each row has its own type and the same editor should edit cells in this row. For this scenario, I think it's better to use the [Vertical Grid](https://docs.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/2465/controls-and-libraries/vertical-grid/layouts/multiple-records-view-layout) instead of the Grid View.

If you still wish to use the Grid View, use the [GridView.CustomRowCellEdit](https://docs.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.GridView.CustomRowCellEdit) and [GridView.CustomRowCellEditForEditing](https://docs.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.GridView.CustomRowCellEditForEditing) events to assign the required editor to a grid cell.